# Using WGET How to efficiently download PDFs from specific URL pattern

Tags: http, unix, web, download, wget

I want to download PDFs from certain locations of a website. There is a main page which has links to sub-pages along with thousands of other links. All PDF links to be downloaded are on sub-pages.

The website is very huge with multilevel links and thousands of links at each level.

I want to optimise downloading using WGET so that

1. only two levels are considered - main-page & sub-page.
2. Only specific type of links are picked on main-page.
3. Folders are named based on the link name on main-page

URL pattern for main page and sub page given below.

Main Page ->

- Page 1 (PDF Link 1 + PDF Link 2 + lots of other links)
- Page 2 (PDF Link 1 + PDF Link 2 + lots of other links)
- ....... so on

URL Patterns

- Main Page (https:// foo.com / mainpage)
- Sub Page(https:// foo.com/mainpage/page/?id=1)
- PDF (https:// foo.com/a/pdf/asda.pdf, https:// foo.com/b/pdf/qwer.pdf)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the wget documentation from this link?https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html

`-r  = recursive
-l depth`

Comment: thanks for the recommendation ... I will go through this in detail, I am not too good with this kind of stuff:)